# How to access multiple instances of stack frame in C

Tags: c, stack, frame

I'm attempting to write a function that is called at the end of a recursive invocation of `foo()`.  This function will access the stack frame to display all passed arguments into `foo()` at the time of each invocation. I am totally confused as to how I can access the stack frame in this manner.  Appreciate any insights on the matter, thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be portable, proper C?

Comment: Not really, I just need to get it working any way I can!

Comment: [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/) is one option if you are on Linux.

Comment: Wait, actually the C code does need to be portable/proper

Comment: @prestige13: All the better to use libunwind or another dedicated library so as to not mess something up :)

Comment: Or if you can modify the recursive function, you could make your own "stack frames", and keep a linked list of them.

Comment: Yes, I second @immibis. Because even if you get access to all the stack frames (via libunwind or otherwise) there is no guarantee that the original function call arguments have been preserved. So OP, you really need to describe the constraints of your problem a bit more. What can and can't be done as part of the solution.

Comment: So the goal is to display all the arguments that have been passed recursively at the end of the recursive chain.  I  need to go back to the start of the stack frame if possible and display all the proceeding stored arguments and local variables.

Comment: I can't use any machine code, only C

Comment: @prestige13 But can you change the way that the recursive function is implemented as suggested by immibis? Or you are not able/allowed to change that function's code? And does it have to be within the running application itself or can you inspect that state from outside the running application?

Comment: Oh I see what you're asking! No I can't modify the code within foo() whatsoever.  My function "recover()" that I'm writing must do all the heavy lifting, although I am allowed to write additional outside functions that recover() can call

Comment: @prestige13 In that case I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. By the time `recover` is called, the arguments to any or all of the recursive calls could have been lost already. AFAIK, there is no guarantee that the args are there in any of the the stack frames at that point in time.

Comment: recover() is called in the last instance of the recursive call.  Does this make it possible as I am calling recover while the recursion is still executing? @kaylum

Comment: No, like I said. There is nothing that says the args need to be pushed onto the stack before calling the next function. Only what is needed is saved onto the stack. The args may no longer be needed at that point in time and hence hence they would not be pushed onto the stack.

Comment: @kaylum It's probably possible, especially if compiling without optimizations.

Comment: @immibis Yes, without optimisations it's probably possible. With optimisations I just don't see how that's possible to do reliably and I would equate that with not possible since it'll be hit and miss depending on the code and the compiler.

Comment: @kaylum  I discovered the best way to go about this is to create a pointer that points to itself thereby giving me the address of recover in the stack frame

void recover ()
{
     int * x  = (int *)&x;
}
The only problem is that my program reaches the recover function and skips over it! I've verified this through GDB.  Can you see any reason why it would do this?

Comment: Unless you have disabled compiler optimisation it is likely that the compiler has removed that function call altogether as it essentially does nothing observable. Not sure if there is a better way, but you could make `x` a global variable to prevent the compiler optimising out the function call. But even that may not work as the compiler may inline the function (and hence no stack).

Comment: Thanks for your help, if I insert a printf statement within the function the program will read the printf statement and output accordingly. But then it will totally skip over the other line.

Comment: Same problem. The compiler can optimise out the whole function but it can also optimise out just those statements that it has determined are not needed.