# returning the call stack in c99

Tags: c, c99, callstack, stack-frame

I have an assignment to write a fuction that returns the stack frame in c99. I have look at some libarys on how they did it such as https://github.com/Nanolat/c-callstack. However, i am not explicitly allowed to use a libary.

I also found this similar question on Stackoverflow, [How to access multiple instances of stack frame in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663546/how-to-access-multiple-instances-of-stack-frame-in-c) however this is mostly left unanswerd and i did not find much help from it. If i have over looked another place on stackoverflow with this answer then please do link it.

**EDIT**: just to clarify i need the call stack

I tried this method

```
void view_stack_frame(void){
printf("%s from (%s:%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
}
```

This returns

```
view_stack_frame from (main.c:423)
```

which is partialy what i need it to do. However, i can not think of a way to display the full stack and not just this part of the stack.

Comment: Then you should ask for a full stack trace I think, not only a stack frame. This usually is system-specific, see for example https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html

Comment: Call stack or stack frame? Very different things.

Comment: There is a discussion and some links _[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105659/how-can-one-grab-a-stack-trace-in-c)_